# Quiz game error

Tags: java, android

I've recently begun programming in Java. I'm using Android Studio to make a quiz game using [this tutorial](https://www.developerfeed.com/simple-quiz-game-andriod/).
Unfortunately, when I do every step of the tutorial, I run the application and it gives me the following error:

[image]

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Could somebody please help?

Comment: linking to the error is discouraged - please edit your post to include it

Comment: You should not post stacktrace as an image. Post stacktrace as text - that's the correct way to post stacktraces.